# How to deploy an assembly with an other artifactId?

Tags: java, maven

Given a maven project with a single module (one single pom.xml) is it possible with maven-assembly-plugin (or an other plugin) to deploy a zip file with an other artifactId than the one of the current pom?

Example
myProject/pom.xml

`mvn package` will produce:

- myProject/target/myProjectActifactId-1.0.jar
- myProject/target/something-1.0.zip

And I want that `mvn deploy` deploys the two files with different artifactIds in my Nexus:

- myGroupId/myProjectActifactId/1.0/myProjectActifactId-1.0.jar
- myGroupId/something/1.0/something-1.0.zip

Comment: Simple question: Why? (And why not simply make another project with exactly that artifact id that uses the assembly plugin?)

Comment: The something-1.0.zip is only constituted of two really small xml files, so creating a parent project with two modules and a new project for that little zip seams a bit too much.

Comment: You can do it using wagon plugin.

Comment: Does this zip file belong to your project?

Comment: yes it does, it shares the same groupId and version number but need to have a different artifactId than the main jar. A classifier is not enough in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution works if you need to install zip file on the local repository. 
    mvn  clean package install:install-file

pom.xml file looks like below

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <goals>
      <goal>install-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <repositoryId>artifactory</repositoryId>
      <packaging>zip</packaging>
      <generatePom>true</generatePom>
      <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <version>${zipfile.project.version}</version>
      <file>path-to-zip-file-created-by-assemblly </file>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Below solution works if you need to deploy the zip to the remote repository.

mvn   package deploy:deploy-file

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <goals>
      <goal>deploy-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <repositoryId>artifactory</repositoryId>
      <packaging>zip</packaging>
      <generatePom>true</generatePom>
      <url>${repository.url}</url>
      <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <version>${zip.project.version}</version>
      <file>path-to-zip-file-created-by-assemblly</file>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```