# SpringBoot: GroupId and ArtifactId based on a property dynamically

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Define GroupId and ArtifactId based on a property file

I would like to know if from Eclipse is possible to set dynamically the GroupId and ArtifactId from a property set on the file `application.properties` in a SpringBoot application
because from the same project I generate 2 different projects (core project and web project) based on `@Profile`

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYUZ9.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why not add it in `pom.xml` file directly? Or may be you are asking to set group id and artifact id dynamically?

Comment: You project structure does not sound right IMHO. Why not split up the project in a effective web and core project? Otherwise see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428275/how-to-deploy-an-assembly-with-an-other-artifactid

Comment: You can add as many properties to application.properties as you want and use those instead, but Spring pulls its BuildProperties values from the pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible to set groupid and artifact id using properties file.But for profile setting using pom directly you can use below option.

"Profiles can be explicitly specified using the -P CLI option.This option takes an argument that is a comma-delimited list of profile-ids to use. When this option is specified, the profile(s) specified in the option argument will be activated in addition to any profiles which are activated by their activation configuration or the  section in settings.xml"

Profiles can be activated in the Maven settings, via the  section. This section takes a list of  elements, each containing a `<profile-id>` inside.

```
<settings>
  ...
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>profile-1</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  ...
</settings>
```

In case of using spring boot you can also apply **spring.profiles.active=profile-1,profile-2**

[CHECKOUT THIS URL FOR FURTHER MORE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to built two or more different jars depending on the active profile set in project.

Maven can support this see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html ,which creates profiles for building and packaging artifacts for different environments.

This feature was meant to support different build environments e.g production,development,testing... but i don't think anyone will be arresting you if you use profiles to modularize your project.